# Using Ryanair online check-in, how to print boarding pass for the return flight?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, check-in, ryanair

I am flying with Ryanair and have managed to print my outgoing boarding pass, but it says you can't print a return until 8 days before departure. What do you do then?

Comment: Next time fly with a company who isn't trying to rob you using nonsense clauses of doubtful legal standing.

Comment: http://www.theguardian.com/money/2014/may/19/ryanair-hidden-charges-booking-online-check-in *sigh*.

Answer (score 8):

You print your boarding pass while at your destination. Make sure you don't forget, otherwise you'd be hit with a [€55/£55 fine](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/termsandconditionsar_1713394128). Your hotel/hostel should be able to print it out for you. If not, visit the nearest internet cafe.

Also note that [Ryanair rarely enforces their rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119007/as-of-2018-does-ryanair-deny-boarding-to-non-eu-passengers-who-skip-the-landsid) on non-EU passengers having to print and confirm their boarding pass, so you could also use a mobile boarding pass instead and most likely you'd be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the mobile boarding pass.

I stopped printing boarding passes for ryanair a couple of years ago.

(if you really want the paper one, your hotel will probably be able to print one copy for you)