# Can I show a Ryanair boarding pass on my phone instead of printing it out?

Tags: tickets

I purchased a ticket from Gdansk, Poland (GDN) to Stockholm, Sweden (ARN) via kiwi.com. Does anyone know how long it typically takes for the boarding pass to become available?

I have heard that Ryanair does not accept boarding passes presented on a mobile device, and that a physical copy is required. Is this correct?

Since I am not checking in any luggage, I was wondering if I can simply use my phone to pass through. Do I need to go to the counter?

I am aware that there are general gates to pass through in Gdansk, and I don't anticipate any issues. However, I am uncertain about the final gate where I will need to present my boarding pass to Ryanair staff.

I have similar concerns at Arlanda airport.

Comment: Have you already checked in with Ryanair? A boarding pass is usually issued after checkin.

Comment: Do people with your nationality need visa for Sweden?

Comment: More specifically, are you an EU/EEA citizen? If not, you have to go to the Ryanair visa/document check desk at the airport before check-in or boarding. And since they will need to stamp your boarding pass, I suppose you’ll need to print it.

Comment: Once I went with wizz and even Ryan air there was no need to do anything except check in online beforehand. I went to the counter show my documents years ago same route,the counter said you have online boarding pass and no check in luggage why did you come to us? go to the gate!

Comment: not an eu citizen but I already have a temporary EU valid resident permit and third party country issued passport. I am sure about what happened to me in Gdansk a few years ago that nobody care about anything since the travel is inside europe maybe they did not care it seems. However, my concern is paper based or the pdf version while going to the last gate entering the plane. Maybe recently it is changed

Comment: Ok. One of my friend told me that he has had lots of travels within the europe in previous month with wizz air and ryanair. His situation is same as to me. He surprised I asked this.He told me is there still paper print out! He just use the pdf in mobile. I will update you here about my trip later. Thanks

Comment: I went from Gdansk to arlanda. No need to paper. Simple mobile scan. Not eu citizen. This is why i highlighted for the people tobanswer based on the experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked in online and the mobile boarding pass easily works. I had lots of travel previously also in many european airports. Yes it works for anybody just do not forget passport specifically if you are not an EU citizen. That simple. No need to be in stress like me. If you dont believe that is ok print it go to the airport use your mobile boarding and then see what is going on.

GOOD LUCK

Comment: Remember that this is an own experience answer and your experience may be different.

Comment: There is no own experience. Ryanair do not need paper boarding pass. Do not force your ideas. I was in 3 diff flights with different nationalities

Comment: Ryanair did not require a boarding pass at that time, in that airport, by those employees, for that flight. There have been many posts here about travelers who have had other experiences. I would not trust that the same outcome will occur for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

In the last few years, Ryanair has introduced a system whereby all people not from the EEA/EU need to have their paperwork checked and stamped to show that it has been checked.

This is not just people that need visas, it includes people with nationalities which would need a visa if they did not have a long term visa for the Schengen area among others.

So your EU resident permit will not help you.

Ryanair has been criticized for it, but they have kept on with it during and after the COVID emergency rules, it is unlikely to change soon.

If you can, print out the boarding pass on paper and do go to the check-in counter, as that is what they expect from you. (The situation can change before you travel and some people have reported not having their paperwork stamped and still be allowed to fly, but others have reported to be sent back to get that stamp. Sorry, no links handy.)

Comment: Thanks, so the one that happened to me two years ago was by chance you mean random? since as I mentioned while going to the counter in Gdansk previous year they told me go to the gate everything is ok! I am sure they did not stamp or do anything!

Comment: I was wondering if recently someone bought a ticket from kiwi.com.. How long normally before the trip the boarding pass will be ready for ryan air? I want to know whether I have time to print

Comment: One more thing about my previous trip. As I highlighted the travel is between two European countries and normally since the first flight is already from a european country thus maybe because of that they do not care too much.

Comment: recently I traveled through some european countries through swissair and it was so strange for me no pass/visa nothing was checked! I checked in online before

Comment: @AhmadTurani Ryanair have their own rules which day they all non-EU/EEA passengers need to have their documents checked. Most other airlines don’t care for intra-Schengen flights. Note that the place for the document check may not be the check-in counter but a separate desk.

Comment: Thanks. Hiwever, there are 2 places at all. Counter and the kast gate. At least in places where I had gone previously.

Comment: If you're a more advanced traveler you can ignore that requirement and just go straight to the gate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119007/as-of-2018-does-ryanair-deny-boarding-to-non-eu-passengers-who-skip-the-landsid. Just be ready to potentially miss this flight if you get an agent who's strict about their idiotic rules.

Answer (score 3):

Kiwi will give you the boarding pass between 24h and 2h before the flight (if you have given Kiwi enough details). It is recommended to print it. https://www.kiwi.com/us/help/what-if-kiwi-com-check-in-service-isn-t-available-237/article/how-do-i-check-in-for-ryanair-flights-306/