# Can I request a visa check to Ryanair customer service in Barcelona?

Tags: visas, ryanair

I'm traveling from Barcelona to Dublin, and I need to do a visa check at the check-in desk. Flying with Ryanair.

Can I do a visa check without going to the same line for the luggages? I don't need to check in anything.

I've read on some forum that you can at the customer service or ticket sale, but it was years back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a visa check with Ryanair in Barcelona, go to where Burger King is (after you enter go further right), passed that area and in between Tax Free and Ryan Air Customer Service is where you can just fall in line and get a visa check. Mixed with other passengers who checks in their luggages.

When you print your boarding pass, it'll say on the very top that it ain't a boarding pass as they force you to do a visa check. There's no barcode to pass through security.

Answer (score 1):

Different airports have different levels of strictness, but the ones that will actually check for the stamp, won’t give you the stamp at the gate. They don’t even have the stamp there. You need to do it at the check-in area. Occasionally you’ll see a dedicated visa check queue, but it’s not usual.

I haven’t heard of going to the customer service desk for a visa check, but it might work. Note that that’s the desk where a queue of three people could take an hour.

Comment: If you're willing to risk your ticket (as many experienced travelers are), you can just ignore the visa check altogether: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119007/as-of-2018-does-ryanair-deny-boarding-to-non-eu-passengers-who-skip-the-landsid

Comment: No, I couldn't. It literally says it on the pre-boarding pass that I should get it checked.

Comment: @Sampaguita that’s the thing he’s saying  you can ignore.

Comment: I should've mentioned that there's no barcode to get to security, so you can't ignore it.